# How can you implement refresh tokens in a web app - angularjs

Tags: angularjs, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, aspnet-contrib, openiddict

I am using token based security in my web app.  The server side is wrote using c# and i am using openiddict for logging in and issuing tokens, found [here](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core).  I am currencyly using Implict flow.

By default my tokens have a lifespan of 1 hour, after that you have to logging again.  I have locked down my API to accept bearer tokens only and not cookies.

I wanted to implement refresh tokens but after reading many websites, it appears that implementing refresh tokens on a web app, is not a good way to go due to a hacker getting the refresh token.  I know that to use refresh tokens, you must use code flow, instead of implict, which i can do.

How do people get round this situation in their web apps?  I cant be the only one who wants a token to last longer than an hour in a web app?

Answer (score 2):

The approach recommended by OpenID Connect is to send an authorization request in **a hidden frame** with the same parameters as the ones you use for the initial implicit flow request plus `prompt=none` and optionally, an `id_token_hint` corresponding to the `id_token` you extracted from the authorization response.

When using `prompt=none`, the identity provider won't display any consent form and will directly redirect the user agent to the `redirect_uri` you specify, with the new token appended to the URI fragment, just like for a classic implicit flow request. You can retrieve it by extracting it from the `popup.location.hash` property.

If the request cannot be processed (invalid request, unauthenticated user, invalid `id_token_hint`, consent required, etc.), an error is returned and the identity provider either redirects the user agent to the `redirect_uri` with an `error` parameter or stops processing the request.

Note that due to the same origin policy, you can't access `popup.location.hash` if the current location belongs to a different domain (e.g if the identity provider refuses to redirect the user agent to your client app): it will throw an access denied exception. In this case, it's always better to add a timeout to your "refresh" operation.

Sadly, there are very few libraries that can help you with this task. [oidc-token-manager](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-token-manager) is one of them, but it has a few limitations that will prevent it from working OTB with OpenIddict: it doesn't support raw RSA keys (you have to explicitly use a X509 certificate in the OpenIddict options) and it doesn't send the `id_token_hint` parameter required by OpenIddict when sending a `prompt=none` request.